# Django2.1.7 ImportError: cannot import name 'util' from 'django.forms' (/Users/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/__init__.py)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, importerror

During migration from Django1.5 to Django2.1.7 we are facing an implicit import error in library function when trying to start server.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x10945f950>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/MAK/Envs/lifemed3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/MAK/Envs/lifemed3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Users/MAK/Envs/lifemed3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/Users/MAK/Envs/lifemed3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/Users/MAK/Envs/lifemed3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/MAK/Envs/lifemed3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/MAK/Envs/lifemed3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 89, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/Users/MAK/Envs/lifemed3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/Users/MAK/Envs/lifemed3/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/MAK/Envs/lifemed3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/json_field/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from json_field.fields import JSONField
  File "/Users/MAK/Envs/lifemed3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/json_field/fields.py", line 4, in <module>
    from json_field.forms import JSONFormField
  File "/Users/MAK/Envs/lifemed3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/json_field/forms.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.forms import fields, util
ImportError: cannot import name 'util' from 'django.forms' (/Users/MAK/Envs/lifemed3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/__init__.py)
```

We have already check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788182/cannot-import-form-in-django) about circular dependency, but as it was in code level and was easily solvable, but in terms of library what would be the best way to solve this?

FYI: we are moving to python3.7 with Django2.1.7 from python 2.7 and django 1.5.5

> UPDATE (Solved)

According to mfrackowiak's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54708822/4040020) below we have to fork their [repo](https://github.com/derek-schaefer/django-json-field), applied [patch](https://github.com/simanto604newscred/django-json-field/commit/517ecf050f6c3462424d24b6c4c6425eec7e9365) for the support and [install](http://pip%20install%20-e%20git+git://github.com/simanto604newscred/django-json-field.git#egg=json_field) from the [changed version](https://github.com/simanto604newscred/django-json-field).  then it worked for me

Comment: Post the relevant code that's giving the error or package name.

Comment: The problem appears to be in the third-party `json_field` library. Which package is that? Are you sure it is compatible with the latest Django version? If it isn't, there are plenty of alternatives that are.

Comment: @ans2human this is in library code :(

Comment: @DanielRoseman django-json-field library, we updated it to the latest version but nothing changes.

Comment: As @DanielRoseman said, there is sadly any chance that this package is compatible with django 2+, as it is [unmaintained for 5 years](https://github.com/derek-schaefer/django-json-field). I would strongly recommend to look for [some alternatives](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/json-fields/) or create your own fork of this library and update it yourself.

Comment: @mfrackowiak   You are correct. I have to fork their repo, applied patch for the support and install from the change version. https://github.com/simanto604newscred/django-json-field/commit/517ecf050f6c3462424d24b6c4c6425eec7e9365   then it worked for me, I wish you would have post it as an answer so that I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it seems that the [package](https://github.com/derek-schaefer/django-json-field) is unmaintained for a long time, the best way to deal with this error would be either look for [alternatives](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/json-fields/) or just fork the repo and update it yourself so it would still work (might be easier than adjusting codebase for another library).

Answer (score 1):

I found these two packages:

- If this is the package you're using [django-json-field](https://pypi.org/project/django-json-field/), then look at the last release which was in 2014 so i'm pretty sure this package is incompatible with `Django 2.0`
- If [jsonfield](https://pypi.org/project/jsonfield/) is your package then even they don't have support for `Django 2.0`. They have 1.8 to 1.11

Post in your code what you intended to do using that package then i might be able to give yo a custom solution or package which actually supports 2.0 and does the work.